# CSS versus JavaScript on drawing borders

Tags: javascript, css, web-frontend

I think there're two ways to draw border on canvas: either through CSS or javascript (operate on canvas context object). My question is should prefer one over the other, and why?

Comment: Stick to `CSS` whenever and wherever possible

Comment: Script just takes more time to load... it's doesn't matter, if you have few scripts on page. But in heavy pages with monster script, CSS win))

Comment: What border are you taking about? CSS can't interact directly on canvas content, so if you want this border to be part of the canvas drawing, you have to draw it from js.

Comment: All I want is the outermost border. Everything else is drawn inside this box. I think my problem is solved.